# Long Press Click Event Handler Vuejs3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, vuejs3, long-click

I need to handle an long press click on my vuejs3 app, but I have not found any viable way that is not from 3 years ago with critical severity vulnerability

I need something like:

```
<button @long-click.on="something()" @long-click.off="somethingElse()"> </button>
```

Comment: Did you looked on how to make a vanilla JS event listener + seconds time? Also, please share the resource, it may maybe be viable.

Comment: vulnerable resource: https://www.vuescript.com/detect-long-press/

Comment: Give a try to [that one](https://github.com/javisperez/vuelongpress) or maybe [this one](https://github.com/ittus/vue-long-click).

Comment: Both are for vuejs 2

Comment: No support for both of them? I guess you will need to do that yourself so. Maybe check Vueuse for something similar, probably is something that could help you. https://vueuse.org/

Comment: Haven't tried Vueuse, let me take a look at it, thanks

Comment: That one for example: https://vueuse.org/core/onlongpress/#onlongpress

Answer (score 0):

i think you can give this one a try:
https://vueuse.org/core/onlongpress/#onlongpress

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { onLongPress } from '@vueuse/core'

const htmlRefHook = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
const longPressedHook = ref(false)

const onLongPressCallbackHook = (e: PointerEvent) => {
  longPressedHook.value = true
}
const resetHook = () => {
  longPressedHook.value = false
}

onLongPress(
  htmlRefHook,
  onLongPressCallbackHook,
  { modifiers: { prevent: true } }
)
</script>

<template>
  <p>Long Pressed: {{ longPressedHook }}</p>

  <button ref="htmlRefHook" class="ml-2 button small">
    Press long
  </button>

  <button class="ml-2 button small" @click="resetHook">
    Reset
  </button>
</template>
```